# Why do i get every time a "Cosine Similarity: 1.0" in python when i compare two different arrays?

Tags: python, cosine-similarity

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
# Define two functions as arrays

numbers1 = np.array([17.5, 114.5, 1.4])
numbers2 = np.array([117.5, 194.5, 1113.4])

function1 = np.sort(np.array([numbers1]))
function2 = np.sort(np.array([numbers2]))

# Reshape the arrays to be column vectors
function1 = function1.reshape(-1, 1)
function2 = function2.reshape(-1, 1)

# Compute the cosine similarity between the functions
similarity = cosine_similarity(function1, function2)

# Print the similarity score
print("Cosine Similarity:", similarity[0][0])
```

Outcome:
Cosine Similarity: 1.0

Where is the problem?

I would expect something between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in ML the standard is to use **row vectors**. And this is how functions are implemented. So your code is not really computing cosine between 2 vectors. You are computing pairwise similarities between 3 **scalars** (so similarity is a 3x3 matrix and you just print 0,0 index of it). And for two scalars cosine similarity is 1 as long as their sign match, which is the case for you.

Just change to row vectors and you get as expected 0.9956

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
# Define two functions as arrays

numbers1 = np.array([17.5, 114.5, 1.4])
numbers2 = np.array([117.5, 194.5, 1113.4])

function1 = np.sort(np.array([numbers1]))
function2 = np.sort(np.array([numbers2]))

# Reshape the arrays to be ROW vectors
function1 = function1.reshape(1, -1)
function2 = function2.reshape(1, -1)

# Compute the cosine similarity between the functions
similarity = cosine_similarity(function1, function2)

# Print the similarity score
print("Cosine Similarity:", similarity)
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue in your code lies in the way you are reshaping and sorting the arrays before computing the cosine similarity. Also cosine_similarity function from scikit-learn expects the input arrays to have the shape (n_samples, n_features), where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features. In this case, since you have one-dimensional arrays, you can simply remove the reshaping step.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

numbers1 = np.array([17.5, 114.5, 1.4])
numbers2 = np.array([117.5, 194.5, 1113.4])


similarity = cosine_similarity(numbers1.reshape(1, -1), numbers2.reshape(1, -1))

print("Cosine Similarity:", similarity[0][0])
```

The reason you are getting a cosine similarity of 1 for those sorted and wrongly shaped two arrays is because they have the same direction. Cosine similarity measures the cosine of the angle between two vectors, and when two vectors have the same direction, the cosine of the angle is equal to 1.

In your case, the functions at the end are:

function1: [[1.4], [17.5], [114.5]]
function2:  [[117.5], [194.5], [1113.4]]

If you calculate the cosine similarity manually, you'll find that the cosine of the angle between the vectors is 1.

Comment: *If you calculate the cosine similarity manually, you'll find that the cosine of the angle between the vectors is indeed 1. This means they have a perfect similarity in terms of direction.* If that was the case, the vectors would have to be scalar multiples of each other. For example, `[1, 2, 3]` and `[10, 20, 30]` would have cosine similarity of 1. But that's not the case for these vectors.

Comment: Here are the steps.Step 1: Calculate the dot product of the two vectors.
```Dot product = (1.4 * 117.5) + (17.5 * 194.5) + (114.5 * 1113.4)```
Step 2: Calculate the magnitude (Euclidean norm) of each vector.
```Magnitude of Vector 1 = sqrt((1.4^2) + (17.5^2) + (114.5^2))```
```Magnitude of Vector 2 = sqrt((117.5^2) + (194.5^2) + (1113.4^2))```
Step 3: Multiply the magnitudes of the vectors.
```Magnitude product = Magnitude of Vector 1 * Magnitude of Vector 2```
Step 4: Divide the dot product by the magnitude product.
```Cosine similarity = Dot product / Magnitude product = 0.995```

Comment: which gives 0.9956, not 1.

Comment: In your code, you reshape the arrays to be column vectors using .reshape(-1, 1). However, this is unnecessary and can lead to incorrect results.

Comment: I'm confused, are you saying that 1 is the correct result? Or that the code is incorrect?

Comment: Also, in your answer you say *"you can simply remove the reshaping step."* But your code performs `.reshape(1, -1)` on each vector.

Comment: The code that you wrote is wrong as you shape it (-1,1) which is not right. When reshaping as you did, you get (3,1) dim array and answer is 1. However, if you reshape it (1,-1), your answer will be 0.9956. Reshaping (1,-1) is must have, but as you have 1d array, doing this step is meaningless

Comment: I didn't write the code. You say the OP's code is wrong (I agree), but you say *If you calculate the cosine similarity manually, you'll find that the cosine of the angle between the vectors is indeed 1. This means they have a perfect similarity in terms of direction.* These are contradictory - is the correct answer 1, or is it not?

Comment: OP code gives 1, because of reshaping it to (3,1) dim. My code gives 0.9956 as I reshaped it (can be skipped as well for the given 2 array) to 1dimension

Comment: Then your answer should be edited to remove the incorrect statment that *If you calculate the cosine similarity manually, you'll find that the cosine of the angle between the vectors is indeed 1. This means they have a perfect similarity in terms of direction.*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and accept the answer if it helped and answered you question

Comment: Sorry, the answer still contains incorrect information. Manually calculating the cosine similarity **does not give a result of 1**.

Comment: The cosine similarity between (1,1) is always 1 or -1 depending on the positivity or negativity of the number. If they are both positive or both negative, the cosine is 1, if one of them is negative and another is positive then the cosine similarity is -1. Because of **wrong shape** in the provied code, the output result is always 1 (because all of them are positve) while calculating it manually as well

Comment: OK, but in the calculation with the wrong reshape, the cosine similarity is not calculated between two vectors. It's calculated between three different pairs of (single-element) vectors. So it's not right to show `Vector 1: [[1.4], [17.5], [114.5]] Vector 2: [[117.5], [194.5], [1113.4]]`. There aren't two vectors: there are two arrays of 3 1-element vectors each.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it, but I think you get the answer to your question at the end. Welcome